# Split file in two using inodes

Tags: linux, filesystems, inode

Would it work to split a file into 2 parts by duplicating its inode, halving the size stored in each, and moving the pointer of the original inode to the half-way point?  This would seem like an efficient way to truncate a log file, which is what I'd like to do instead of rotating it to a completely new file.

I've read a little about inodes and realize this could be dangerous (I don't know all the reasons why, though I suppose the program that has the file open could end up with an invalid offset into the file), but it still seems like it should be pretty simple to do, as long as it's okay to split the file at a block boundary, rather than at a particular character.

If possible, how might this be accomplished?

My goal would be to set a limit on the size of a log file, and to do that by pruning instead of rotating.

EDIT: I'm missing something in this question, because the inode contains size, but not a pointer to the blocks that have been allocated (referring to the struct at the bottom of http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Inodes.html).

Comment: If you can split at page boundary it is possible at least in theory. Practically there is some work to do :-) and an implementation of this should be in kernel to guarantee FS coherence.